# Android pull-to-refresh with custom ListView adapter

Tags: android, listview, custom-controls, pull-to-refresh

Am trying to implement chrisbane's pull-to-refresh library for my ListView (https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh).  It seems simple enough but what Im having trouble with is the fact it seems to require it's own data set, seperate to what's managed by your list adapter, i.e.

```
mListItems = new LinkedList<String>();
mListItems.addAll(Arrays.asList(mStrings));
```

All the examples I've seen just use this simple list of strings, but how do you go about using this with any kind of custom adapter, such as one that that contains a string and an imageview, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There're plenty of examples on this site and around.
You create your adapter and set this arraylist as a field  there 
or usually set as a constructor parameter. 
You @override `getView()` of this adapter and get your items using `position` parameter
in the `getView()`. Here look at the `OrderAdapter` class in this example:
http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/
and here at the `GameAdapter` class
http://jnastase.alner.net/archive/2010/12/19/custom-android-listadapter.aspx

---

hope this helps abit

Comment: Ah, turns out I was reading the examples completely wrong.  I understand custom adapters like you linked, but somehow had it that they were adding data to the PullToRefreshListView separably to the adapter.  That's not the case though, so the rest is easy :) Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.